# Idempotent Merges in GitHub

Tags: git, github, merge

My team has recently implemented a deployment strategy that automatically kicks off our build and deployment process to a different environment every time a merge is completed targeting the relevant environments branch.  These branches are protected requiring that we have at least one reviewer before merging into these branches.

Initially it appeared straight-forward that we should rebase the main development branch onto each environments branch to deploy the relevant code; however, with how GitHub handles rebasing and merging, we are seeing the same commit having a different SHA on the target branches.  This causes the commit to appear multiple times on the environment branch during subsequent pull requests.

> The rebase and merge behavior on GitHub deviates slightly from git rebase. Rebase and merge on GitHub will always update the committer information and create new commit SHAs, whereas git rebase outside of GitHub does not change the committer information when the rebase happens on top of an ancestor commit.

https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/configuring-pull-request-merges/about-merge-methods-on-github

Is there a way to maintain our intended flow in GitHub without changing the commit hash every time we perform a merge, or should we rethink how we're performing this deployment strategy?

Comment: Can you just use a regular merge (with a merge commit) instead of rebase? Then the commit IDs are preserved. Also, if you really want a fast-forward merge, you can create the PR and push it from a client. It will only succeed if all checks on the PR have passed.

Comment: @TTT We essentially have an integration and production branch for each environment. The merging strategy involves us merging from feature > int > prod. 
Wouldn't this create a second, duplicative merge commit, by the time we're merging into the "prod" branch?  If not, this may be what I'm looking for.

Comment: Yes, you would have extra merge commits if you PR into `int` and then PR `int` into `prod`.  Is `int` a long-lived shared branch as well as `prod`? If yes, it's not *that* bad to have those merge commits there, as they provide a historical representation in the first-parent log view of exactly which set of commits were brought in together, and when. That being said, some people simply don't like merge commits and don't care about that extra information, and in that case you'd have to merge locally with fast-forward and push it out.

Comment: You're right, it's probably not that bad to duplicate these.  We'll look at this as an option, thanks!

Comment: You will _always_ get new commit hashes when you rebase (even with vanilla Git). It's impossible to keep the hashes of rewritten commits. I'm not sure what the GitHub docs are trying to say. (Maybe that if you rebase to the same base, hashes remain identical because nothing is actually rebased? I really don't know.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For posterity, I figured I'd follow this up with the results.

Ultimately since there's no reasonable way to perform this through GitHub without creating unnecessary commits, my team decided to go back to using a single protected branch for code deployments.